# How to union json string with row_to_json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
        select row_to_json(a) from (
            select id, title, body, page_total from TMP 
            offset page_size*(page-1)
            limit page_size
        ) a;
```

And other query like this:

```
select '{"a":1,"b":2}'
```

**How do I union these selects?**
When I try this:

```
select '{"a":"1"}'::json
union
select row_to_json(a) from (
    select id, title, body from news
    offset 0
    limit 5
) a;
```

It gets error:
ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 1: select '{"a":"1"}'::json
^
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb` instead:

```
select '{"a":"1"}'::jsonb
union
select to_jsonb(a) from (
    select id, title, body from news
    offset 0
    limit 5
) a;
```

Comment: thanks, it works but how do i remove f1 key and get only value from row result {
  "f1": {
    "id": "CnZt9T3t6pY65WzqQihxo5ipsE4LrFe3",
    "body": "Body 1",
    "title": "Title 1"
  }
}

Comment: i mean { "id": "CnZt9T3t6pY65WzqQihxo5ipsE4LrFe3", "body": "Body 1", "title": "Title 1" }

Comment: That's a different question, isn't it?

Comment: no, it the same

Comment: Your question was how to write a union with JSON data without getting an error.

Comment: i'm sorry for my missing, can you help me again?

Comment: Simply omit the `ROW`.